# Number formatting in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

I have some problem here. I got to SELECT a column which the result i.e. '01201698765'. How to split this number to becoming like this : '01.2016.98765'.

I've used TO_CHAR, but the '0' (zero) number at the front was gone.

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention. the type is CHAR. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

- **SUBSTR**
- **concatenation operator** `||`

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT '01201698765' num FROM dual
  3  )
  4  --end of sample_data mimicking real table
  5  SELECT num,
  6         substr(num, 1, 2)||'.'||substr(num, 3, 4)||'.'||substr(num, 7) num_formatted
  7  FROM sample_data;

NUM         NUM_FORMATTED
----------- -------------
01201698765 01.2016.98765

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column is a string, just use string operations:

```
select substr(col, 1, 2) || '.' + substr(col, 3, 4) + '.' + substr(col, 5, 5)
```